# Django session last_touch

Tags: django, session

my middleware code is as below:

```
class AutoLogout(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

       # if not request.user.is_authenticated():
       if (request.COOKIES == None):
            # Can't log out if not logged in
            return

       if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
            try:
                logout(request)
                del request.session['last_touch']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
       return self.get_response(request)                                                 The eroor i am getting is KeyError: 'last_touch'
```

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.

Comment: I am getting error as  KeyError: 'last_touch'..How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try/except block isn't laid out correctly to catch and deal with the `KeyError`.  It can occur in three places, but you're only catching one.   The logic is a bit janky, but just editing what you have, I think this is what you're trying to achive:

```
try:
     if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
          logout(request)
          del request.session['last_touch']
          return self.get_response(request) 
     else:
          request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
          return self.get_response(request)  
except KeyError: #KeyError thrown if last touch doesn't exist, so set it. 
     request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Thanks its no longer showing error...but its not automatically logging out after 2 minutes.